# How to manually update time in time zone?

Tags: time, timezone

There was a time change in Europe (-1h) but my system didn't change it :( What can I do? My time zone is correct (checked with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`).

Answer (score 0):

Set the time manually using the `date` command or install `ntpdate` using the software center.

Comment: `ntpdate is already the newest version.`. What can be wrong?

Comment: If it's already installed, then execute ntpdate, type this into a terminal window: `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the timezone, please follow the below steps.

1. open the terminal and run the command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" then choose the correct timezone from the menus.
2. Then edit the file "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" and change the setting "date.timezone" to be the correct timezone for your location. There is a list of all the supported timezones.
3. Reboot the machine and check whether the timezone is updated properly.